# Get random term page from a specific category with wiki api

Tags: php, mediawiki-api

I am trying to get a random *term* article from the wikipedia. The [API:Random](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Random) page lists only three parameters I can pass to the request. None of them seem to do what I want to achieve.

My question is - is it possible to get a random article from a specified category and is it possible to get a term page.
Example of what I mean by saying a "term" article - [subtraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction), reciprocity, api (I can't link the last two because I don't have enough rep).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes, but not through the proper API. There is a special page in MediaWiki that allows for something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory

However, it does not take parameters. But there is also this tool: http://tools.wmflabs.org/magnustools/randomarticle.php which will do the trick.

It will allow parameters like in this example: http://tools.wmflabs.org/magnustools/randomarticle.php?lang=en&project=wikipedia&categories=Pop+music&d=3

`lang` is the language of the Wikipedia you want (in this case en for English), with `project` you could use other projects (like Wikibooks or Wikiquote), `categories` is what you are looking for and `d` can be used if you want to look in the subcategories of that category (to that level).

Comment: I am trying different category like `sport`, `film`. But nothing is working Suppringly the only working categories is `Pop+music`. I am trying `http://tools.wmflabs.org/magnustools/randomarticle.php?lang=en&project=wikipedia&categories=Movies` but it is not working -- Redirecting me to the home page

Comment: It is because it is not used as a category. You have to look up on Wikipedia that the category actually exists. If you try Films, it works, example: http://tools.wmflabs.org/magnustools/randomarticle.php?lang=en&project=wikipedi%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Ba&categories=Films&d=1