# How can I get a random article in a specific category from the Wikipedia API?

Tags: wikipedia-api

This is my link for getting one random article using Wiki API:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?%20format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exsentences=2&exintro=&explaintext=&generator=random&grnnamespace=0
```

I need to get from it the first two sentences of the first section, and it works pretty well.

---

I want to use this kind of link and search this random article in a specific category. This is what I have tried after searching online:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?%20format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exsentences=2&exintro=&explaintext=&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&cmtitle=Category:Music
```

(I have added this part to the original link: `cmtitle=Category:Music` )

It doesn't work for me.
It gets the random article like the first link (not under a wanted category, which is Music in this link).

Comment: Doesn't work how?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Check if the answer to this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520429/get-random-term-page-from-a-specific-category-with-wiki-api not JSON but surely it can be parsed to suit

Comment: Yeah I have seen this post already, but I'm asking because I need to information in JSON format. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to get a random category member (and using a parameter from some unrelated API module is certainly not going to help). You could screen scrape [Special:RandomInCategory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory) (or turn it into an API module - [patches welcome](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T63840) :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `cmlimit` to get all of the catgeorymembers, then use a programming language, like [Python](https://python.org) to request the page, then store every catgeory in an array, and use the `random` module to get a random catgeorymember from the array you stored them in. then you can use it in a link to get the specific page for the categorymember or anything else that you need.